# Dropdownlist in edit mode of a gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

In my application in c#, when I edit a row in the gridview I choose some new data from a dropdownlist.

I am populating the dropdown like this:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Gender">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="gender" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("gender").ToString() %>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DDL_genderList" runat="server">
            <asp:ListItem Value="" Text="---"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="M" Text="M"> </asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="F" Text="F"> </asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </EditItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

But when I press the 'Edit' button from the template and enters in the 'RowUpdating' event, the selected value from the dropdownlist is every time the first value from that dropdownlist.

I need selected value in dropdownlist it's the value which displays in Label gender.

Does anyone have any ideas?

I've tried many ways to set the selected value in the 'RowDataBound' event, but with no luck.

I tried this:

```
protected void gvProducts_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    DataRowView dRowView = (DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem;

    if ((e.Row.RowState & DataControlRowState.Edit) > 0)
    {
        DropDownList genderList = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("DDL_genderList");
        genderList.SelectedValue = dRowView[1].ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: use     <asp:DropDownList ID="DDL_genderList" runat="server"  SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Gender") %>'>

Comment: thanks but for closed question?

Answer (score 0):

You have to find Label from TemplateField (DataRow) and DropDownList from EditTemplate (EditRowState) as like:

```
protected void gvProducts_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        // find gender from label which is inside ItemTemplate
        string lblgender = ((Label)e.Row.FindControl("gender")).Text;

        if ((e.Row.RowState & DataControlRowState.Edit) > 0)
        {
            // find gender list from dropdownlist which is inside EditTemplate
            DropDownList genderList = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("DDL_genderList");
            genderList.SelectedIndex = 
                genderList.Items.IndexOf(genderList.Items.FindByValue(lblgender));
        }
    }
}
```

I know this is very late answer but it can help to the OP.